# git won't recognize windows folder is a linux symlink - status shows link files as deleted and symlink target contents as untracked

Tags: linux, windows, git, symbolic-link, network-drive

I cloned a repo to a network drive on a linux machine, then opened the cloned repo on a windows machine. the repo has linux style symlinks in it, that windows interprets (correctly) as folders. the problem starts when I do a git status on the windows machine. it shows the symlinks as deleted and the files in those folders as untracked (obviously, the files do not exist in the symlinks, but in the original locations).

My question is, can this situation be fixed? so that the symlinks are interpreted correctly as symlinks, and give me access to the locations they point to, while not messing up my git repo?

Comment: Answered here: [Git symbolic links in Windows - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symbolic-links-in-windows)

Comment: I would argue that if Git checked out these symlinks as _folders_ (without the shortcut icon), this is already wrong. It must either use native symlinks or junctions or… nothing.